# Confused about Office365 API's?

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-apps

So I'm developing an app using my school/work Office account. I'm basically trying to access my own information, my profile picture, and possibly the directory of users (+10000, Do I need the administrators consent for this? I'm just a standard user). I see on the API developer page (https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/getstarted and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/auth_overview) I see two types of API's: The Azure AD and the Azure AD V2.0. Then it says for the Azure V1.0 API I should register on the portal. That works fine, I can go on to portal.azure.com with my school/work account and add my app. Now when I try to go to Azure AD V2.0 registration portal, that supposedly works for work/school accounts, I get greeted by the microsoft live login page, which I do not have. Now my question is, do I need to use Azure V2.0 API to achieve these things or is the Azure V1.0 API enough? And is the Azure V1.0 API only for live accounts then?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end! You can sign up to the Azure V1.0 API with a work/school account!